# Expanding $n \sin ({\pi \over n})$

Tags: taylor-expansion

How to expand $n \sin \left({\pi \over n}\right)$ as
$$
n \sin \left({\pi \over n}\right) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} { (-1)^{m-1}\over (2m-1)!} \left({\pi\over n}\right)^{2m-1}\cdot n
$$
and why? Since it resembles the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ at $x=0$, any connection and if so why are they connected? Thanks!

Comment: This is simply the Taylor expansion of $n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ for $x=\pi$. There is not much else to say.

Comment: This equality could be used to approximate $\pi$, as an analogy with Romberg's Extrapolation.

Comment: @MaxYoung There are much better ways to compute $\pi$, see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

Answer (score 1):

The equality as written is wrong; the right hand side is the Taylor expansion of $\sin(\frac{x}{n})$ (evaluated at $x = \pi$) while the left hand side is the same now multiplied by $n$.

Comment: Thanks! It's my typo... Well, it struggled me why this expansion is very much the same as the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ at $x = 0$, and I've now understood, since the radius of convergence for $\sin(x)$ at any point is $R=\infty$.